# PushViewController not working

Tags: ios4, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

i want to create a basic push view scenario. I have the following code but it does not work. Nothing happens. Could someone tell me why?

```
testController *screen2 = [[testController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:screen2 animated:YES];
[screen2 release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do an NSLog to see if screen2 is nil. Chances are it is not being appropriately loaded from a corresponding nib for some reason. As an aside, I'd highly recommend sticking to the convention of capitalizing class names. Speaking of which, did you maybe call the nib file TestController.nib? (That would cause the problem.)